# In Xcode6, why does [CMAltimeter isRelativeAltitudeAvailable] returns FALSE when run in Simulator with iPhone6?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, ios-simulator, core-motion

Is there any way of testing altitude code prior to having my hands on an iPhone 6?

`[CMAltimeter isRelativeAltitudeAvailable]` returns `FALSE` when run in Simulator with iPhone6.

Comment: That seems logical to me.

Comment: What a silly question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to all of the other Core Motion (CM) classes, CMAltimeter does not work in the simulator and requires an iPhone 6 or 6+. Though some people have rigged accelerometer and gyroscope simulators that can augment the simulator, it took a long time for this to be created and there is no such equivalent for CMAltimeter.